# Как найти число в массиве ? obj-c

Tags: objective-c

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
            [mas_m addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:rand() % 2]];
        }
for (i_in in mas_m) {
          if (i_in==1) {
                NSLog(@"Yeah");
            }
        }
```

Выдает ошибку... в чем причина?

Answer (score 5):

NSDecimalNumber - это не число, а объект, и сравнивать его вы можете лишь с числом, сначала превращённым объект. Далее, при сравнении объектов NSDecimalNumber посредством `==` сравниваются не числа, но объекты, которые содержат в себе эти числа, поэтому сравнивая два разных объекта NSDecimalNumber, пусть и содержащих одно и то же число, вы будете получать NO (false).

Вот правильная запись:

```
if ([i_in isEqualToNumber:@(1)])...
```

`isEqualToNumber` сравнивает между собой именно числа, которые содержат в себе два соответствующих экземпляра NSDecimalNumber.

См. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNumber (в первую очередь описание isEqualToNumber:)

```
NSDecimalNumber, an immutable subclass of NSNumber, provides an object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic...
```

Соответственно, всё написанное здесь о NSDecimalNumber имеет место и в случае его родителя NSNumber.

Comment: Спасибо!
Я так понимаю числа следует добавлять как 
[mas_m addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:arc4random() % 10]];  ?

Comment: Да, вы всё правильно делаете.